# How to submit your mobile app for sensitive scope review to Google?

Tags: google-play, google-oauth, google-fit

Our mobile app requires sensitive scopes (Google Fit). It's all setup and implemented. We're going back and forth with the review team now for 2 weeks because they can't access the application.

How do you submit your app for sensitive scope review?

We've created a "closed testing" release in Google Play Store and added the reviewers email as a tester. When they want to access the closed test application in Google Play Store they see an error "Your administrator has not given you access to this item".

Since every response takes 3-5 days I'm hoping someone here has some advice on how to best do this.